# Starting In Python: Jump To Start

Tags: python-3.x

I'm Just Starting In Python (3.7), And I Want To Make A OS, I Know I Will Not Be Able To Boot From It But Its Just A Project Im Working On. So This Is My Code So Far:

```
import os   
import time 
import sys  
print("Charlie OS Python Edition Desktop")
print("What App Would You Like To Open? Remember To Type The Apps Number To Find All The Apps Type 1")
AppNumber = input("Type Here: ")
if AppNumber == "1":
    print("2 = Text Editor")
    print("3 = Shutdown Charlie OS Python Edition")
    time.sleep(5.5)
if AppNumber == "2":
    print("Not Coded Yet")
    time.sleep(2.2)
if AppNumber == "3":
    print("Goodbye!")
    time.sleep(2.2)
    sys.exit
```

Made In Sublime Text 3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you like to elaborate more on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @VasilisG. Im Trying To Make It Go Back To The Start Of The Code In Python After time.sleep(5.5) In if AppNumber == "1":

Answer (score 0):

You can place the code which check for user input in a `while` loop:

```
import os   
import time 
import sys  
print("Charlie OS Python Edition Desktop")
while True:
    print("What App Would You Like To Open? Remember To Type The Apps Number To Find All The Apps Type 1")
    AppNumber = input("Type Here: ")
    if AppNumber == "1":
        print("2 = Text Editor")
        print("3 = Shutdown Charlie OS Python Edition")
        time.sleep(5.5)
    if AppNumber == "2":
        print("Not Coded Yet")
        time.sleep(2.2)
    if AppNumber == "3":
        print("Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(2.2)
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: I Added The Code And Every Time I Open My Python File It Just Closes

Comment: I Run It Through A Shortcut Called "Start Charlie OS" Mabey Its The Version Of Python? I Have Python 3.7

Comment: Try running it from the console. You also have a syntax error in `sys.exit`. It should be `sys.exit()`.

Comment: I Get An Error On Line 6 (IndentedError: expected an indented block)

Comment: It must be because you're mixing tabs with spaces. Try converting the tabs into spaces and it should work.

Comment: This Might Be Stupid Thing To Say But I Have Been Programing For Almost 2 Years An I Don't Know What Tabs Are.

Comment: A tab is a number of consecutive space characters acting as one character. Try deleting this line and check if it works.

Comment: I Get The Same Error As Before But For AppNumber = input("Type Here: ")

Comment: Change `sys.exit()` to `sys.exit(0)` or just `exit(0)`. Then remove all trailing whitespaces and replace all tabs with spaces (1 tab = 4 spaces). I just ran it from terminal on Linux with Python 3.7.2 and it worked fine. You should also take a look at the [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3) ;-)